# Ajax only submitting first form in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have an issue with my ajax function only submitting the first form in my foreach loop.

I have a post/comment system, each comment on each post has an individual id. When i use this without ajax the comments submit well and link to the correct comment. When i try this with ajax i only manage to get the first ID of the first form in the loop to submit.

The `$value->id` is the id of the post which the comment will be associated with.

Below is my code for the comment form:

```
 <form onsubmit="submitCmt(); return false;">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input style="border-radius: 0px; box-shadow:none; border-left: none; border-right:none;" class="form-control add-comment-input" placeholder="Add a comment..." type="text" id="postCmt">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="post_id" value="<?= $value->id; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="<?= $value->user_to; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="logged_in_id" value="<?= $logged_in_id; ?>">
                                    <button id="cmtBtn" class="btn btn-default" style="border-radius: 0px; box-shadow:none; border-right:none;">Post</button>
                                </span>
                            </div><!-- /input-group -->
                        </form>
```

And Below is my Ajax function:

```
    function submitCmt() {
var postCmt = _('postCmt').value;
var post_id = _('post_id').value;
var user_id = _('user_id').value;
var logged_in_id = _('logged_in_id').value;

    _("cmtBtn").innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw'></i>";
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "process.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            _("cmtBtn").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajax.send('postCmt='+ postCmt + '&post_id='+post_id + '&user_id=' + user_id + '&logged_in_id='+ logged_in_id);
}
```

I am quite new to using Ajax. I have viewed similar posts but have struggles to apply it to my code effectively.

Thanks in advance! Sam

Comment: where is the loop?

Comment: `<?= $value->id; ?>` is it okay?

Comment: this is because `ajax` is asynchronous but `for-loop` is not

Comment: When i echo the $value->id on each form in the loop it displays the correct id for that post

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE user_to = $user_id ORDER BY id DESC";

    $obj = $db->select($query);

    foreach ($obj as $value) {

     $queryC = "SELECT * FROM user_comments WHERE post_id = $value->id";
        
      $objC = $db->select($queryC);

      $count = count(array_filter($objC));

     $user = $this->load_user_object($value->user_from)
     ?>

Comment: this is the loop, there is more code between this but only containers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have several such forms on same page, which means that you have e.g. this several times, once for each form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="<?= $value->user_to; ?>">
```

This creates many fields with duplicate id called `user_id` which is not allowed, since each id must be unique.

You also do not select the form you want in any way, so there is no telling which value commands like `_('post_id').value` returns. Could be first or could be something else.

To fix you could just add form id to these so that they are unique:

```
<input type="hidden" id="user-<?= $value->post_id; ?>" value="<?= $value->user_to; ?>">
```

Alternatively give each form an id, and change those input-field ids to be names:

```
<form id="form-<?= $value->post_id; ?>" onsubmit="submitCmt(); return false;">
...
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?= $value->user_to; ?>">
```

Then you need to change your selector to select form with given ID, and then field inside it with given name. (I don't know syntax for this, since I don't know which library you are using here.)

Comment: is there a way of giving each form an id then calling the ajax for that form? i currently use the 'on submit' to call the ajax function

Comment: and when running the PHP loop each form does get unique id's '$value->post_id'.

Comment: Thanks Markus, that looks like it would be what I am looking for. I am just trying to use raw JS to get myself used to using Ajax. Appreciate the help